# Java - Splitting a String based on a String and a new line

Tags: java, arrays, string

I want to produce an array that splits a string based on either a string of text within it that it called `"stop"` and I also want to split based on the presence of a new line (`\n`).

However, it doesn't seem to split based on the presence of a new line, how would I do this? So far I have:

String[] myArray = str.split("stop");

But I want to include splits are a new line, but I can't seem to do this through the methods I have tried.

The data returned is a string containing something such as the following:

**data1**`stop`**data2**`stop`**data3**`\n`

So I would want to put the strings data1 and data2 into the array, and then also data3 into the array without the additional line.

Comment: Do you want an array (1 dimension) or a matrix (2 dimensions)? I mean sould data1stopdata2stopdata3\ndata4stopdata5stopdata6\n give {"data1","data2","data3","data4","data5","data6"} or{{"data1","data2","data3"},{"data4","data5","data6"}}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `split("stop|\\n")`. The argument to `String#split` is a String that contains a regular expression.

Have a look at http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html and http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html. They discuss exactly your problem.

Comment: if his string is `data1stopdata2stopdata3\n` your method will give `data1
data2
data3\n`

Comment: @RanRag That does seem to split the string successfully. I also have a if statement for data3 that equates it to another string without the \n, this returns true, so I can only assume the \n is removed after the split too. Why do you think it leaves the data\n with the line? And if I'm wrong please describe how, and why.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that if you want to get a system independent line separator, you better use:

```
System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't something like this work:

```
String[] a=str.split("(stop|\\n)");
```

Untested though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
String number = "data1stopdata2stopdata3\\n";
String[] number_array = number.split("stop|\\n");

for(String s: number_array)
System.out.println(s.replace("\\n",""));
```

Output = `data1
data2
data3`

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.split("Stop|\\n");` e.g

```
    String str = "Data1\nData2StopData";
    String[] a = str.split("Stop|\\n");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

Will give [Data1, Data2, Data]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the given answers, I'd rather user `split("stop|\n")` instead of `split("stop|\\n")`. The first expression uses Java's built-in support for line feed, whereas in the second the regular expression "\n" is interpreted as a line feed. So there's less overhead in the first expression.

Answer (score -2):

You can use [Google Guava Splitter](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html).on(Pattern p) method. Set your pattern to include "stop" as well as "\\r?\\n"